# Non-Toy Software Transactional Memory for C or Java

Tags: java, c, transactions, shared-memory

I'm thinking about the possibility of teaching the use of Software Transactional Memory through 1 or 2 guided laboratories for a university course. I only know about Haskell's STM, but the students of the course probably never heard a word about it.

I already found some lists of such libraries online or in other questions (e.g., http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_transactional_memory#C.2FC.2B.2B). I'm checking them out as you read this, but many of them do not seem to have a very nice documentation (most are research prototypes only vaguely described in papers, and I would rather teach about something more used and well documented).
Furthermore, many of the links provided by wikipedia are dangling.

**To sum it up**, are there STM implementations aimed to industrial projects (or at least non-toy ones, to ensure a certain level of quality) and well documented (to give some good pointers to the students)?

**EDIT**: I'm not the teacher of the course, I just help him with the laboratories. Of course the students will be taught basics of concurrency and distributed algorithms before. This was just an idea to propose something different towards the end of the course.

Comment: All right, please comment about how to improve the question instead of downvoting and proposing the closure. The point is quite simple: I need a simple and well documented implementation.

Comment: Agree. Nothing worse than anonymous downvoters and closers.

Comment: I didn't downvote but can only guess that down/close vote was because the question hints at a lack of research.  The first link returned by googling "software transactional memory" is a Wikipedia page linking to implementations in C, Java and many other languages.

Comment: @simonc: I guess you may be right, even though I already pointed out that I searched online. What I want is the opinion of someone with some experience, since I don't have much time to try out so many implementations for now. I'll add some hints about what I found so far. Thanks.

Comment: I think "can you recommend.." or "what is the best.." questions are closed as "Not Constructive" on SO.

Comment: I'm not asking for reccomendations. I'm asking for a list of well-documented implementations. I could not find any with a good documentation so far...

Comment: Did you look as DeuceSTM? It's used in couple university as a teaching tool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Production-quality STM-Libraries are not intended as a **teaching tool**, not even as "best practice". What is worth learning for any college/university-course is maybe **1%** of the code; the remaining 99% is *nitty-gritty platform-dependent intrinsic corner-cases*. The 1% that is interesting is not highlighted in any way so you have no way of finding it.

What I recommend for a college/university-course (no matter if introductory or advanced) is to implement STM-buildingblocks yourself (and only for 1 platform).

Start by introducing the problems: concurrency, cache...

Then introduce the atomic helpers we have: cas/cmpxchg, fence.

Then build examples together with your students, first easy, then harder and more complex.

Comment: I was searching for production-quality implementations in order to have something with a wide community and documentation behind, but I did not intend to give them a wide comprehension of such a framework, just the 1% in order to see basic STM mechanisms in action.
Your proposal however is MUCH better than my idea. I think I'll propose to go for this to the teacher, and see if he's ok with dedicating some labs to make the students implement basic STM mechanisms. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

> Start by introducing the problems: concurrency, cache...

Leading on from [eznme](https://stackoverflow.com/users/618598/bernd-elkemann), some good problems that I covered while at University for `concurrency`.

- [Dining philosophers problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem)

  > In computer science, the dining philosophers problem is an example problem often used in concurrent algorithm design to illustrate synchronization issues and techniques for resolving them.
  >
  > [image: dining phil]
  >   <sub>(source: [wikimedia.org](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6a/Dining_philosophers.png/200px-Dining_philosophers.png))</sub>

Using the same implementation from [here](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~jnm/book/book_applets/Diners.html), by Je Magee and Je Kramer, and solving the problem using monitors.

Most shared memory applications are more efficient with `Integers` than Strings (due to `AtomicInteger` class for Java). So the best way to demonstrate `shared memory` in my opinion is to get the students to write an application that uses a `threadpool` to calculate prime numbers, or to calculate some `integral`.

Or a good example of threads and shared memory is the [Producer-consumer problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem).

> The producer-consumer problem (also known as the bounded-buffer problem) is a classic example of a multi-process synchronization problem.
>
> [image: producer]
>   <sub>(source: [csusb.edu](http://cse.csusb.edu/tong/courses/cs460/images/producer-consumer.gif))</sub>

Implementation found [here](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~jnm/book/book_applets/TimedProducerConsumer.html), there is also an implementation from [Massey](https://www.massey.ac.nz) from the professor in Software Eng [Jenz Dietrich](https://sites.google.com/site/jensdietrich/).

For distributed algorithms [MapReduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) and [Hadoop](https://hadoop.apache.org/) are highly documented distributed data structures. And for Distributed Programming Libraries look into [MPI (Message Passing Interface)](http://parallel.vub.ac.be/documentation/mpi/index.html) and [OpenMP](https://web.archive.org/web/20161107020950/http://openmp.org/wp/) (or [Pragma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preprocessor_directive) for C++). There is also implementations of [Dijkstra shortest path algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm) in [parallel](https://www.mcs.anl.gov/~itf/dbpp/text/node35.html) too.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question in order to clarify the context. The course is about concurrent and distributed programming/algorithms, and I'm not the teacher. There will be plenty of background on the topic, both during lessons and laboratories. This about transactions would only be an extra: I'm not searching for more examples to talk about, so I think eznme's proposal may be the best fit.

Comment: @Riccardo okay, that's fine. Just sharing the examples I was shown when learning concurrency and atomic transactions.

Comment: @Riccardo Updated the answer for links to distributed algorithms/data structures and libraries.

Answer (score 1):

There are three good ways to do STM today.

The first way is to use gcc and do TM in C or C++.  As of gcc 4.7, transactional memory is supported via the -fgnu-tm flag.  The gcc maintainers have done a lot of work, and as of the 4.9 (trunk) branch, you can even use hardware TM (e.g., Intel Haswell TSX).  There is a draft specification for the interface to the TM at http://justingottschlich.com/tm-specification-for-c-v-1-1/, which is not too painful.  You can also find use cases of gcc's TM from the TM community (see, for example, the application track papers from transact 2014: http://transact2014.cse.lehigh.edu).

The implementation itself is a bit complex, but that's what it takes to be correct.  There's a lot of literature on the things that can go wrong, especially in a type-unsafe language like C or C++.  GCC gets all of these things right.  Really.

The second way is to use Java.  You can either use DeuceSTM, which is very easy to extend (type safety makes TM implementation much easier!), or use Scala's Akka library for STM.  I prefer Deuce, because it's easier to extend and easier to use (you just annotate a method as @Atomic, and Deuce's java agents do the rest).

The third way is to use Scala.  I've not done much in this space, but researchers seem to love Akka.  If you're affiliated with a parallel/distributed class, you might even be using Scala already.